# タグの「burninate」（バーニネート／焼尽／消滅）とは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, タグ

「タグをburninateする」とは、どんな意味ですか？

Answer (score 3):

タグの「burninate」は、特定のタグを消滅させることです。日本語を当てるならば「焼尽」「消滅させる」などが考えられます。

#### ミームとしての「burninate」

「burninate」とは、 アニメ「[Homestar Runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestar_Runner)」のキャラクター「Trogdor the Burninator」から生まれたミーム、あるいはジャーゴンです。焼き払う、焼き尽す、といった意味合いで[使われます](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burninate)。

画像: [I made us some Trogdor graphics!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/i-made-us-some-trogdor-graphics)
動画: [Strong Bad Email #58 - Dragon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90X5NJleYJQ&t=183s)

#### Stack Exchangeでの「burninate」

Stack Exchangeサイト群で、あるタグを「burninateする」と言うのは、そのタグを消滅させる行為です。

##### やり方

- 質問からの削除: 対象のタグが付けられた全ての質問をユーザーが編集し、そのタグを削除します。
- タグの消滅: 上が完了すると、そのタグは孤立タグ（質問がゼロのタグ）となるので、[自動プロセスにより消滅](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/)し、[タグwikiは孤立](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299399/)します。

自動化ツールなどは有りません。あまりに対象の質問が多い場合は、Stack Exchange社に依頼することも考えられますが、それは特別なことです。

##### 事前の相談や合意

- 数件の場合: 対象のタグが付いた質問が数件程度であれば、自身の判断で行なって構いません。これは綴りの間違ったタグなどに対し、日常的に行われています。
- 多数の場合: ただし、質問の数が多い場合はメタサイトで事前に相談し、コミュニティーの合意を得るのが安全です。このサイトでは明確な基準や、事前に決められたプロセスは有りません。サイトによってはプロセスが詳細に定められています（[Stack Overflow英語版の例](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/)）。

##### 完了後

- 再作成: 消滅したタグ名を使用するのは、新規にタグを作るのと同様であり、[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)が有れば可能です。
- 検索: 「burninate」に限りませんが、質問から既に削除されているタグで検索する方法はWebインターフェースには有りません。しかし、マージとは違い、質問にタグを付与した際の編集履歴にはタグ名が残っています。この履歴は例えば、[Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)の`PostHistory`テーブルで検索が可能です[（例）](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1811400/search-for-text-in-a-posts-tag-related-history?SearchText=%3Coffice%3E)。

#### 参考

- [What does it mean to "burninate" a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/)
- [Meta Stack Exchangeのタグ `burninate-request`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info)
- [英語版メタサイトのタグ `burninate-request`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info)